# can we use js variable name as class name in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to concatinate class name with variable count which keep getting updated after each button click, for which I am getting error as "citysName is null". can anyone suggest

```
button.addEventListener('click', resp => {
    count = count +1;
    var card = document.createElement('card');
    card.innerHTML = `
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  **<h5 class="card_title" + count></h5>
                  <h6 class="temp" + count></h6>
                  <p class="card-text" + count></p>**
                  <a href="#" class="btn-primary"></a>
                </div>
    `;
    card.className = 'card';
    var content = document.getElementById('id1');
    content.appendChild(card);
    **var citysName = document.querySelector('.card_title'+count);
    var description = document.querySelector('.card-text'+count);
    var temp = document.querySelector('.temp'+count);**
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputVal.value+'&appid=a5599c020b0d897cbc8b52d547289acc')
    .then(post => post.json())
    .then(data => {
        var cityName = data['name'];
        var temper = data['main']['temp'];
        var descrip = data['weather'][0]['description'];

        let ctemp = Math.round(temper-273);
        citysName.innerHTML = cityName;
        temp.innerHTML = ctemp + "°C";
        description.innerHTML = descrip;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all thats not how you add variables using template literals you can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Second why do you query it again when you've just made the element you can use `card` as reference and if you need something within it, its much easier to access it using the variable you already have other than looking for it in your document

Maybe something like this but its hard to tell withouth more code etc

```
button.addEventListener('click', resp => {
    count = count +1;
    var card = document.createElement('card');
    card.innerHTML = `
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  **<h5 class="card_title${count}"></h5>
                  <h6 class="temp${count}"></h6>
                  <p class="card-text${count}"></p>**
                  <a href="#" class="btn-primary"></a>
                </div>
    `;
    card.className = 'card';
    var content = document.getElementById('id1');
    content.appendChild(card);
    var citysName = card.querySelector('.card_title'+count);
    var description = card.querySelector('.card-text'+count);
    var temp = card.querySelector('.temp'+count);
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputVal.value+'&appid=a5599c020b0d897cbc8b52d547289acc')
    .then(post => post.json())
    .then(data => {
        var cityName = data['name'];
        var temper = data['main']['temp'];
        var descrip = data['weather'][0]['description'];

        let ctemp = Math.round(temper-273);
        citysName.innerHTML = cityName;
        temp.innerHTML = ctemp + "°C";
        description.innerHTML = descrip;
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks solved the issue, currently learning it